# passar varios anexos via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jersey

Olá pessoal meu primeiro post aqui, estou com um problema para enviar mais de um anexo via Ajax. tenho uma API em jersey que recebe a chamada. se eu enviar apenas um anexo funciona de boa, porem se eu selecionar mais de um anexo, chega apenas um.

Minha função que passa

```html
function gravar() {
  var campo = document.getElementById('id').value;
  
  
  $('#mensagem_success').hide();
  $('#mensagem_danger').hide();
  var conteudo = JSON.stringify($('#frmProposta').serializeObject());

  $.ajax({
   url : "https://url",
   type : "POST",
   contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType : "json",
   data : conteudo,
   success : function(result) {

    $('#mensagem_success').html(' Gravado com Sucesso');
    $('#mensagem_success').show();

   },

   error : function() {
    $('#mensagem_danger').html('Erro ao gravar ');
    $('#mensagem_danger').show();

   }

  });
  
  
  // Get form
  var form = $('#frmProposta')[0];
  var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;
  
  

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
      
  
  var nome = files[i].name
  
  
  
   
  // Create an FormData object
  var data = new FormData(form);
  
  

  $
    .ajax({
     type : "POST",
     enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
     url : "https://url",
     data : data,
     processData : false,
     contentType : false,
     cache : false,
     timeout : 600000,
     success : function(data) {

     
    
     },
     error : function() {

    

     }
    });

  }
 

 };
```

Meu formulario

```html
<form class="form-group" name="frmProposta" id="frmProposta">
        <div class="box-body">
         <!--  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="cod_user">Código do usuário *</label>
                 
                </div> -->
                 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" >
         
      
        <div class="box-body">
          
         
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="email_usuario">Tematica</label>
           <select class="form-control"name="tema" id="tema">
           <option>Tematica</option>
           <option>Inovação</option>
           <option>Emprego</option>
           <option>Segurança</option>
           <option>Infraestrutura</option>
           <option>Mobilidade</option>
           <option>Economia</option>
           <option>Educação</option>
           <option>Lazer</option>
           <option>Saúde</option>
           <option>Tecnologia</option>
           <option>Outros</option>
          </select>
         </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="nome_login">Resumo*</label> <input type="text"
          class="form-control" id="resumo" name="resumo"
          placeholder="Resumo" maxlength="400"> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  col-md-6">
         <label for="senha">Descrição*</label> <textarea cols="10" rows="5"
          class="form-control" id="descricao" name="descricao"
          placeholder="Descrição" maxlength="400"></textarea> 
        </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="nome_login">Situação Atual*</label> <textarea cols="10" rows="5"
          class="form-control" id="situacao" name="situacao"
          placeholder="Situação Atual" maxlength="400"></textarea> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  col-md-6">
         <label for="senha">Indicadores*</label> <textarea cols="10" rows="5"
          class="form-control" id="indicadores" name="indicadores"
          placeholder="indicadores" maxlength="400"> </textarea> 
        </div>
         <div class="form-group  col-md-6">
         <label for="senha">Observações*</label> <textarea cols="10" rows="5"
          class="form-control" id="obs" name="obs"
          placeholder="Observações" maxlength="400"> </textarea> 
        </div>
        
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="nome_login">Arquivo</label><input type=file "multiple"
           id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" size="100" />
         </div>
         
        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer col-md-12">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
          onclick="gravar()">Salvar</button>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
         <button type="reset" class="btn">Limpar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Qual a relação com java?

Comment: API que recebe é em java

Comment: Mas não tem nada de java na pergunta.

Comment: Articuno, peço desculpas pela ma formação de tags. já ajustei

Comment: Você não esta passando o mesmo como um `array`, `name="uploadFile[]"`